# Best way to use System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker with lambda in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, backgroundworker

I want to know the best way to do that:

```
using (var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker())
{
    DoWorkEventHandler doWorkHandler = null;
    doWorkHandler = (s, e) =>
        {
            //Some expensive code goes here...
            backgroundWorker.DoWork -= doWorkHandler;
            //or
            //((BackgroundWorker)s).DoWork -= doWorkHandler;
        };
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += doWorkHandler;

    RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler workerCompleted = null;
    workerCompleted = (s, e) =>
        {
            //Update IU or something...
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted -= workerCompleted;
            //or
            //((BackgroundWorker)s).RunWorkerCompleted -= workerCompleted;
        };
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += workerCompleted;

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

x

1. I imagine that I really need to remove the handler to avoid leak or something. Right?
2. Witch is the best, access the BackgroundWorker instance trought the "s" parameter or by the variable backgroundWorker?Is it the same?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? May be better to spawn a thread and use the Dispatcher to update the UI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) What do you mean exactly? To remove the "doWorkHandler"?
If so, you don't need to do that (as far as I know).
Just as **Ale** said, you just need that to reuse the same bgw.

But for the **using**, I wouldn't go that way.
Just my way of implementing but for bgw I would stick with a variable contained within the class.

---

2) Access will work fine both ways (general use). It's "better" to use the "s" but you'll have to typecast everything so the code will become harder to read.
Personally I would use the variable declaration instead (direct access) instead of the "s" object.

---

Now, there's something new.
Take a gook look at the Task library.
Might be a goo way to go (I've found that many times it's better and easier than using the Background Worker).
And you can build parallel tasks as well =)

Comment: I mean basically to remove "doWorkHandler" and "RunWorkerCompletedHandler". I think that if I don't remove that handlers the references last "forever".

Comment: Aditionally to second answer I don't know if the "closure" created by using variable created outside lambda brackets can decrease performance. Because the framework need to create a "closure" with that variables but it really creates even if you don't use?

Comment: GC will pick up the background worker once it goes out of scope; this will remove the handler references.

Comment: Just as **Ale** said, the Garbage Collector will handle the references once they are not used anymore. You can also tune up the GC for better performance. You could also extend the BGW class and implement a Dispose() method of your own. Just keep in mind that the "normal approach" (doing nothing with the references) does _not_ impact performance (at least not so much) on **this** scenario since the handler will be gone after the method runs (because of the using).

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to remove the handler, unless you are reusing the same BackgroundWorker instance somewhere else. However, given that you are surrounding it with a Using, this shouldn't be a problem (the scope of your worker is the using statement in this case).

Also, access to the backgroundWorker instance should work either way, however, when cycling data around I often like to use the userState instead which comes back in the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.